# $Assumption for multiple variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to restrict my variables to certain ranges for my entire notebook, is there a way I can do that in one go without entering a different $assumption line for every variable?

Edit: I want to define the domain of variables for all calculations in my notebook (googling helped me frame my needs better!)

Comment: Just to understand a little better. Suppose you do Restrict[a,{0,1,2,3}] with a certain function Restrict[]. What is your expected behaviour if you later do a=5 ?

Comment: How about `$Assumptions = Element[#, Reals] & /@ {a, b, c, d}`

Comment: @Yaroslav That is actually equivalent to `$Assumptions = Element[{a, b, c, d}, Reals]`, but for more general range restrictions, you're right. A simple `Map` should work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Exactly what domain are you working with and is it the same for all variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your variables are going to be (for example) `Real`, then you can [intercept the creation of new symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InterceptingTheCreationOfNewSymbols.html) and add that assumption to `$Assumptions`.  E.g.

```
$Assumptions = True;
$NewSymbol = If[#2 === "Global`",
    Print["Created new Global` variable named ", #1, ". It is assumed to be real."];
    $Assumptions = $Assumptions && Element[Symbol[#2 <> #1], Reals],
    Null (* other, probably a system symbol is created *)] &;
```

Then if you create a new symbol that you don't want to be real, then you could follow up with something like `$Assumptions = Most[$Assumptions]`.

---

Note: I don't necessarily claim that this approach is a good idea...
It's probably best to just define the `$Assumptions` for the variables you are going to use. This can be done programmatically using `Map`, `Table`, etc.

Comment: I remember working in some version of BASIC where the first char of a variable name defined its type ...

Comment: @belisarius Yeah... that brings back some memories. It would be quite easy to modify my answer to behave like that.

Comment: @simon & belisarius If you were ever forced to worked with M$-style C-code, you would see the practice of naming by type taken to its horrible extreme. Google/Wikipedia tells me it even has a name: [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Answer (score 4):

Globally define as follows

```
$Assumptions = b >= 0 && c >= 0 && {u11, u13, u14} \[Element] Reals
```

then use globally defined variables as follows

```
Simplify[expression  with global variables]
```