# User defined Function coloring in Mathematica

Tags: function, colors, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a trick to assign a specific color to "user-defined" function such as "function" below :

```
function[x_]:=x^3
```

Thanks to Mr.Wizard we are able to color all user defined symbols ( [Syntax Coloring In Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130514/variables-coloring-in-mathematica))

Would there be a way to refine the solution to have different colors for Functions symbols, Variables symbols & Options symbols ?

### EDIT : Image for Simon

[image]