# Moving contexts with $NewSymbol in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was playing around with `$NewSymbol` trying to find something to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6165977/421225) with. [The docs say that](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$NewSymbol.html)

> $NewSymbol is applied before the
>   symbol is actually created. If the
>   action of $NewSymbol causes the symbol
>   to be created, perhaps in a different
>   context, then the symbol as created
>   will be the one used.

So I tried to automatically move a particular new symbol into a test context which should prevent its creation in the `` Global`* `` context, but the symbol gets created in both contexts.

```
In[1]:= Remove["Global`*"]
In[2]:= $NewSymbol=(Print[#1," : ",#2];
                    If[#1==="aLongTestSymbolName"&&#2==="Global`",
                       Symbol["TestContext`"<>#1]])&;

In[3]:= x
During evaluation of In[3]:= x : Global`
Out[3]= x

In[4]:= aLongTestSymbolName
During evaluation of In[4]:= aLongTestSymbolName : Global`
During evaluation of In[4]:= aLongTestSymbolName : TestContext`
Out[4]= aLongTestSymbolName

In[5]:= Names["Global`*"]
Out[5]= {aLongTestSymbolName,x}

In[6]:= Names["TestContext`*"]
Out[6]= {TestContext`aLongTestSymbolName}
```

I believe that `"aLongTestSymbolName"` should not be in the `` Global` `` context.
Can anyone see what I've done wrong or if I've misinterpreted the documentation?

---

Note: Having the symbol created in both contexts is not an option for the automatic highlighting in the above linked to question. The idea is to reserve certain symbol names such as `"x"~~___` for variables and `"f"~~___` for functions and then use string patterns in `$NewSymbol` to move the symbols to the appropriate highlighted context.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you passed the symbol name to `Print`, which immediately made the symbol in `` Global` ``. :-)

Or not.  I should really try things before answering, but I thought I knew this one.  Oops.

---

It seems to me now that `$NewSymbol` does not intercept the creation of a symbol, or if it does, how to make use of that is not clear.

If one uses:

```
$NewSymbol = Print["Name: ", #2, #] &;
```

then:

```
In[10]:= aNewSymbol

During evaluation of In[10]:= Name: Global`aNewSymbol

Out[10]= aNewSymbol
```

We see that `$NewSymbol` does not work like `$PrePrint` in that its output does not become the expression.

Therefore, if we use:

```
$NewSymbol = Symbol["TestContext`" <> #] &;

aSecondSymbol
```

`aSecondSymbol` is merrily created in `` Global` `` as though nothing had changed.

If `$NewSymbol` can be used to direct the context in which the symbol is created, as the documentation states, it is not clear to me how this may be done.

Comment: W - Actually, in your example `aSecondSymbol` is created in both `` Global` `` and `` TestContext` ``.  
Do you think the documentation is wrong then? Maybe it worked in an older version but got broken and no one noticed... I guess I should ask WRI.

Comment: @Simon, that's correct.  My point was that it is still created in ``Global` `` apparently completely independently from anything that is invoked by `$NewSymbol`, and that `Print` / `If` etc. are unrelated to the problem.  I hope that Michael, Daniel, or Sasha will stop by with an answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like one of our local friendly WRI employees has stopped by - so I sent a bug report to WRI.

Comment: @Simon Have you got any response from WRI?

Comment: @Alexey: My email was added to an existing bug report. We might hear more when v9 is released...

Answer (score 0):

In [this Mathematica Journal article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v6i2/columns/wagner/wagner62.pdf) about context issues you may find that just the presence of a new symbol in the parsing phase of the  evaluation will add this symbol to the current context. In this case aLongTestSymbolName is handed to the Print and If as #1 and is therefore created in the current context `` Global` ``. I don't think there is anything you can do in the `$NewSymbol` function to prevent this.

The article mentions that even if you use `` Begin["Context1`"]; someSymbol; End[] `` someSymbol is not placed in the `` Context1` `` context unless `` Begin["Context1`"] `` is evaluated on a separate line.

Comment: see the answer I just undeleted.  I think it's not right, because the symbol and context names are passed as strings, according to the documentation.

Comment: @Mr.Wiz hmmm, yerright. Perhaps mma does something similar to a ToString[symbol] before passing? That would then create the symbol.

Comment: The docs say that $NewSymbol is evaluated before the symbol is created. I imagine that new symbol code is called by `MakeExpression` when it encounters a unknown string. But before it creates the symbol it runs $NewSymbol with that string as an argument.