# List all User-defined Variables & Functions in a Notebook in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, user-defined

Is there a way to list all the user-defined variables & function in a Notebook ?

I would like this for the comfort it brings to a notebook overview as well as to spot potential multiple use of a variable name (thus redefining it accidental)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To find names in a context, say in the Global context, try

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

--Nasser

Comment: More straightforward: `Names[$Context<>"*"]`.

Comment: & Alexey, Thank You ! 
Would you think about a way to list separately the Function, Variable or options used ? 
Many Thanks.

Comment: @500, I do not know how to find if it is a function you defined, but for build in function, this is how I do it 
    isFunction[name_String]:=Module[{m}, If[Length[SyntaxInformation[Symbol[name]]]>0,True,False]];
for example: isFunction["Plot"] will return True.
 this works only for functions which have synatxInformation.

Comment: Is `Names[$Context<>"*"]` more straightforward because it gives the current context instead of assuming that the current context is Global?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a friendly interface to pop up, try the standard information printing character `?` or `??`

You can apply it to the global namespace as:

```
?Global`*
```